# Simple HTML Website (followup)

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Followup to [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/193161/simple-html-website-with-javascript-navbar)

---

I have created a simple HTML5/CSS3/JS website with a navbar and no content.

---

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>SigmaCubes - Home</title>
  <meta name="author" content="Julian Lachniet,Simon Kwilinski,Jacob Wysko" />
  <meta name="description" content="SigmaCubes is the best website on the internet." />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Noto+Sans|Nunito:600|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/lib/css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/lib/css/sigmacubes.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />
  <script src="/lib/js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <noscript>
      <div class="error">
        <h1>Error:</h1>
        <h2>JavaScript</h2>
      </div>
    </noscript>
    <!--[if IE]>
      <div class="error">
        <h1>Error:</h1>
        <h2>Old Internet Explorer</h2>
      </div>
    <![endif]-->
    <div id="nav-stupid" class="error">
      <h1>Error:</h1>
      <h2>Resolution</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="nav-large">
      <img alt="SigmaCubes Logo" class="logo_h" height="24" src="/img/logo_h.svg" />
      <div id="nav-large-links">
        <a class="link-large" href="#">About Us</a>
        <a class="link-large" href="#">Projects</a>
        <a class="link-large" href="#">Contact</a>
        <a class="link-large" href="#">Donate</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="nav-small">
      <img alt="SigmaCubes Logo" class="logo_h" height="24" src="/img/logo_h.svg" />
      <a class="link-nav" onclick="toggleNav()" href="javascript:void(0);">
        <img height="28" src="/img/menu.svg" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="nav-small-links">
      <a class="link-small" href="#">About Us</a>
      <a class="link-small" href="#">Projects</a>
      <a class="link-small" href="#">Contact</a>
      <a class="link-small" href="#">Donate</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

reset.css:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p,
blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img,
ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i,
center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption,
tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section,
summary, time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

main.js:

```
var navEnabled = false;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', main);

function main() {
  setDisplay("wrapper", "block");
}

function toggleNav() {
  if (navEnabled) {
    setDisplay("nav-small-links", "none");
  } else {
    setDisplay("nav-small-links", "block");
  }
  navEnabled = !navEnabled;
}

function setDisplay(id, state) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = state;
}
```

What can I try to improve?

Answer (score 1):

#### `title`

It’s [better for usability](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/59858/17633) to use "page-title - site-name" instead of "site-name - page-title".

But for the homepage, you might want to omit the page-title ("Home"), as the site/domain name only typically represents the homepage.

```html
<title>SigmaCubes</title>
```

#### Error messages

You shouldn’t use a heading element for the content, as this creates an outline that’s not useful. Use `p` instead. And to [convey the importance of the error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13522180/1591669), you could use the `strong` element.

```html
<div class="error">
  <h1>Error</h1>
  <p><strong>Old Internet Explorer is not supported</strong></p>
</div>
```

You should add the [`hidden` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute) to your error messages, and remove it as soon as the error becomes relevant. Otherwise the markup affects your outline (i.e., you have all possible errors listed at the top of the document outline).

```html
<div class="error" hidden>
```

```html
<div id="nav-stupid" class="error" hidden>
```

(For the error about disabled JavaScript, you’d need to add the `hidden` attribute via JS itself, of course.)

#### `alt` for logo

The `alt` attribute for a logo shouldn’t contain the term "logo" (unless that’s part of the name, of course). Just use the site name.

```html
alt="SigmaCubes"
```

#### Navigation

Use the `nav` element for the navigation.

Use a `ul` element for the navigation links (without a list, you should use some kind of textual delimiter separating the navigation links, e.g. for text browsers).